# How to change colour of graph in a particular area?

Tags: ios, xcode, bemsimplelinegraph

I am using BEMSimpleLine graph in my IOS application. I want to change the graph colour in some selected areas. Means, currently the graph colour is blue, and from x-axis point 5 to point 10, I want to make it green colour. The rest of the other graph areas should be in blue colour only. How can i do this?

Current Graph Image

[image]

Required Graph Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the areaBaseValue and areaFill properties. The base value is the lower boundary of the filled area. This is normally set to the location value of the yRange so that the fill starts at the bottom of the plot area, but it doesn't have to be. The fill can be any CPTFill—a solid color (with optional transparency), an image, or a gradient. For example:

```
plot.areaFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]];

plot.areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromInteger(0);
```

Comment: Where to do these changes? `BEMSimpleLineGraphView.m` or in `ViewController.m` ?

Comment: In BEMSimpleLineGraphView.m

Comment: What you mean by `plot`?

Comment: Are you use CPTPlotRange class or not?

Comment: No. I am not using CPTPlotRange class.

Comment: CPTPlotRange *range = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(4.0)
                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(6.0)];
CPTFill *bandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
[yAxis addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:range
                                                          fill:bandFill]];

Comment: I am using [BEMSimpleLineGraph](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph) to draw this line graph. There is no CPTPlotRange class.

Comment: Please follow this link you may get your answer.

Comment: Let me check. Thanks.